# ASP.Net Core MVC - Run client side script/function after form submit data success

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have this code that generate the form.

```
    <form asp-controller="home" asp-action="EditClient" method="post" class="mt-3" id="EditClientForm">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label asp-for="Client.Client" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label"></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <input asp-for="Client.Client" class="form-control" placeholder="Client Name" id="editClient">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label asp-for="Client.ClientCode" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Client Code</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <input asp-for="Client.ClientCode" class="form-control" placeholder="Client Code" id="editClientCode">
                    </div>
                    @*<div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="custom-checkbox" style="padding: 0.375rem 0.1rem;">
                                <label asp-for="ClientActive">
                                    <input asp-for="ClientActive" /> Active
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>*@
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            </form>
```

and this is the code in controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> EditClient(SetupViewModel newModel)
    {
            Employee employee = await employeeRepository.GetEmployeeByPhoneNumber(((ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity).FindFirst(AccountConstant.PhoneNumber).Value);
            var model = HttpContext.Session.GetComplexData<SetupViewModel>("SetupModel");
            foreach (var project in model.Projects)
            {
                project.ClientCode = newModel.Client.ClientCode;
                project.Client = newModel.Client.Client;
                await projectRepository.Update(project, employee);
            }
            model.Client.Client = newModel.Client.Client;
            model.Client.ClientCode = newModel.Client.ClientCode;

            HttpContext.Session.SetComplexData("SetupModel", model);
            return RedirectToAction("Setup", "Home");

    }
```

After submit process successfully, i want to show a success modal. How to do that ?
I have search to use Ajax but i don't really understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways you can do this. For a small project I am working on a simple mechanism will suffice and I am using TempData.  I have a static extension method for a controller class. I simply add a message and display in the action which is then shown in the layout used by all views

```
/// <summary>
/// Add a message to a list of messages in Tempdata
/// </summary>
/// <param name="c"></param>
/// <param name="message"></param>
public static void AddTempDataMessage(this Controller c, string message)
{
    // assume a new list
    var messages = new List<string>();

    // check if object already exists
    object m = c.TempData.Peek("Messages");

    // object stored as a string array for simplicity
    if (m != null && m is string[] v)
    {
        // set existing array to the list
        messages = v.ToList();
    }

    messages.Add(message);

    // Store as a simple array since using a List<string> changes to string[] on redirect (Microsoft bug?)
    c.TempData["Messages"] = messages.ToArray();
}
```

Example action usage

```
    if (imageExists != null)
    {
        this.AddTempDataMessage("Image already in set");
        return RedirectToAction("EditImageSet", new { imageSetId });
    }
```

Usage in shared layout view

```
// A list of messages to display
List<string> Messages()
{
    // assume a new list
    var messages = new List<string>();

    // check if already exists
    object m = TempData["Messages"];

    // stored as an array of strings since a redirect changes a list to an array so we stored it as an array
    if (m != null && m is string[])
    {
        // set existing
        messages = ((string[])m).ToList();
    }

    return messages;
}



        @* Messages *@
        <div class="text-danger">
            @foreach (var m in Messages())
            {
                <span class="mr-2">@(m + ".")</span>
            }
        </div>
```

Comment: I'm confused with your answer. Which part of code that run client side script ?

Comment: Your form does not use AJax but simply posts back a form. You therefore do not need to run any client side scripts. You add messages to TempData which is displayed when the next page loads from your redirect. the messages exists between pages. You can PEEK TempData to look at values but once you read them they are gone.

Comment: I get error message "There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'message' of 'HomeController.AddTempDataMessage(Controller, string)'"

Comment: In order to work, Firstly, The static extension method AddTempDataMessage must be within a public static class such as - public static class ClassExtensions {... Second, your controller must inherit from class Controller (which it probably does).

Comment: Thanks for your idea. I modify a bit to this inside a "$(document).ready" with

"var message = "@TempData["Messages"]";
            if (message) {
                $('#message').text(message);
                $('#popupInfo').modal('show');
            }"